# window.location.href not redirecting

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hope this is not a silly question.

I am using window.location.href to redirect to a new page. but it seems it is not working.

Here is the part of my code: (in my local host: MyProjects/QuizApp/main/index.php)

```
 if (score >= min_scores[i] && score <= max_scores[i] ) {
                window.location.href = page_links[i];
            }
```

page_links[] array has the redirect urls. (http:youtube.com)
I am testing in my local server. When this line is executed the browser points to

```
http://localhost/MyProjects/QuizApp/main/http://www.youtube.com.
```

As you can see the redirect url is appended to current url.

Why is this happening? How can I fix this?

Thanks,

Comment: and why is there a `.` at the end of the url?

Comment: @Alrazah THE ROOT http://youtu.be/72snZctFFtA?list=FLH7SoEkZBFJhFX7Pd6K0tpQ

Comment: and why are you trying to execute javascript in a php file

Comment: Your url is wrong, it is http:// , no http//:, in this way, browser treat it like a relative url, not an absolute one

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a string( `"..."` ):

```
window.location.href = "http://www.youtube.com";
```

Comment: The above script works, what exactly is in `page_links[i]`? Is it `"http://www.youtube.com"`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your `page_links` are missing the `//` in the url after `http:`.

http:youtube.com

should be

http://youtube.com

or

http://www.youtube.com